# Displaying Elements Outside of Scrollable DIV

Tags: html, css

I've got a side bar that scrolls vertically. I'd like to implement popovers that appear to the side of elements in the side bar, outside of the side bar's normal area.

Unfortunately the W3C spec has this aggravating peculiarity

> The computed values of 'overflow-x' and 'overflow-y' are the same as their specified values, except that some combinations with 'visible' are not possible: if one is specified as 'visible' and the other is 'scroll' or 'auto', then 'visible' is set to 'auto'.

The side bar scrolls vertically using `overflow-y: auto`. Using absolute positioning on our popover items the resulting position is relative to the closest positioned ancestor.

If that ancestor is within the `overflow-y: auto div` it results in horizontal scrolling instead of the desired behavior because `overflow-x: visible` is interpreted as `overflow-x: auto`.

If the closest positioned ancestor is above the `overflow-y: auto`  declaration it displays relative to that ancestor.  That means it can be displayed next to the side bar, which is good. It also defaults to `top: auto` , which means that on page load it will display in the correct place vertically, which is also good. However this value is static, so if you scroll the content in the side bar the element does not move with its parent.

I've included a minimal reproduction to demonstrate the issue. Note how tooltip 3 displays outside of the side bar like it should, but does not move when vertically scrolling. Tooltip 4 on the other hand moves with the parent while scrolling like it should, but displays inside the side bar (creating unwanted horizontal scrolling).
Does anyone have a suggestion for a workaround better than manually setting and updating all the top values for the popovers with javascript?

```
<div style="position: absolute; width: 200px;">
    <div style="background: #666; width: 100%; height: 200px; overflow-x: visible; overflow-y: auto;">
        <ul>
            <li>item 0</li>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
            <li>
                <div style="width: 100%; float: left;">item 3</div>
                <div style="position: absolute; left: 100%; width: 50%;">tooltip 3</div>
            </li>
            <li style="position: relative;">
                <div style="width: 100%; float: left;">item 4</div>
                <div style="position: absolute; left: 100%; width: 50%;">tooltip 4</div>
            </li>
            <li>item 5</li>
            <li>item 6</li>
            <li>item 7</li>
            <li>item 8</li>
            <li>item 9</li>
            <li>item 10</li>
            <li>item 11</li>
            <li>item 12</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i had similar issue , here is example of my solution:

```
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .box {
        /* margin-left: 100px; */
        height: 100px;            
        width: 200px;
        background-color: bisque;            
    }
    
    .sideBar {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: aqua;
    }
    
    .container{
        height: 100px;            
        overflow-x: visible;          
        overflow-y: auto;  
        
    }
    .item{
        margin-left: 100px;
        background-color: yellow;
        position: relative;
    }

    .floating{
        position: absolute;
        left:-90px;
        z-index: 2;
    }

<div class="sideBar"></div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">
            <p class="floating">floating 1</p>
            <p class="staic">item 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <p class="floating">floating 2</p>
            <p class="staic">item 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <p class="floating">floating 3</p>
            <p class="staic">item 3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <p class="floating">floating 4</p>
            <p class="staic">item 4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <p class="floating">floating 5</p>
            <p class="staic">item 5</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <p class="floating">floating 6</p>
            <p class="staic">item 6</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <p class="floating">floating 7</p>
            <p class="staic">item 7</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <p class="floating">floating 8</p>
            <p class="staic">item 8</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <p class="floating">floating 9</p>
            <p class="staic">item 9</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <p class="floating">floating 10</p>
            <p class="staic">item 10</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).